# create sequence of numbers which are cyclic

Tags: r, sequence

I have a vector of months

```
m_vec <- c(3, 7, 11)
```

These months represent the start month of a season. All the months in each season are shown below:

```
season1 <- c(3,4,5,6)
season2 <- c(7,8,9,10)
season3 <- c(11,12,1,2)
```

I want to create a small function that takes a vector of start months and
generate the vector of months in each season. Some more examples are show below:

```
m_vec <- c(9,12,4,8)
season1 <- c(9,10,11)
season2 <- c(12,1,2,3)
season3 <- c(4,5,6,7,8)

m_vec <- c(12, 5, 9)
season1 <- c(12, 1, 2,3,4)
season2 <- c(5,6,7,8)
season3 <- c(9,10,11)
```

My for loop is not complete and I can't seem to even know where to get started with the logic

```
n_season <- length(m_vec)
temp_list <- list()
for(m in seq_along(m_vec)){
      
   month_start <- m_vec[m]
   month_start_next <- m_vec[m + 1]
    
   month_start:month_start_next
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we can create some helper functions

```
cycle <- function(n) { function(x) (x-1) %% n + 1 }
split_at <- function(b) { function(x) split(x, cumsum(x %in% b)) }
```

The `cycle()` helper will return a function that will keep values in the range from 1 to the `n` you pass in. It does that using the modulus `%` operator. The `split_at` helper will return a function that takes a vector and splits it up when the values you pass in are found. It does that by using `cumsum()` to count when each of the break points are found.

Then we can take your input, create a vector of 12 months from your first starting month, wrap in in a cycler to keep it from 1-12, and then we can use split it up using your season breakpoints. Here's what that would look like:

```
month_cycle <- cycle(12)
season_splitter <- split_at(m_vec)

m_vec <- c(12, 5, 9)

seq(m_vec[1], length.out=12) |>
  month_cycle() |>
  season_splitter()
# $`1`
# [1] 12  1  2  3  4
# $`2`
# [1] 5 6 7 8
# $`3`
# [1]  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m_vec <- c(12, 5, 9)
Map(function(x, y) head((((x:(x + ((y - x) %% 12))) - 1) %% 12) + 1, -1),
    m_vec,
    c(m_vec[-1], m_vec[1]))
#[[1]]
#[1] 12  1  2  3  4

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6 7 8

#[[3]]
#[1]  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to convert to `Date` class, get the `seq`uence and extract the `month`s

```
library(lubridate)
fn1 <- function(mvec) {
    new <- pmax(mvec-1, 1)
    out <- Map(function(i, j) {
       date1 <- mdy(i, truncated = 2)
       date2 <- mdy(j, truncated = 2)
      if(date1 > date2)  {
        date2 <- date2 + years(1)}
       month(seq(date1, date2, by = "month"))
       }, mvec, c(new[-1], new[1]))
    if(length(out[[length(out)]]) < 2) {
           out[[length(out)-1]] <- c(out[[length(out)-1]], out[[length(out)]])
           out[[length(out)]] <- NULL
   }
    names(out) <- paste0("season", seq_along(out))
    return(out)
  }
```

-testing

```
> fn1(m_vec)
$season1
[1] 3 4 5 6

$season2
[1]  7  8  9 10

$season3
[1] 11 12  1  2

> fn1(c(9, 12, 4, 8))
$season1
[1]  9 10 11

$season2
[1] 12  1  2  3

$season3
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
> fn1(c(1, 5, 11))
$season1
[1] 1 2 3 4

$season2
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

$season3
[1] 11 12  1
```